# How to move event handler to a parent form and pass eventargs

Tags: vb.net, recordset

In form 2 I have a datagridview filled with search results of a database.

My goal is that when a cell in the datagridview is clicked, it fills out the contents of textboxes on form 1 by passing the index of the row clicked and the recordset to a function in the code for form 1.

In form 1 I have the following:

```
 rs = New ADODB.Recordset
 rs .CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
 rs.Open("Exec " & class_Stored_Procedures.cs_spMyO_KontaktPersonen_SEA$ & " " & SQL$, gConnectionString$, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenKeyset, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)
 Dim f = New ChildForm()
 f.Show()
 f.Focus()
 f.getAdoRecords(rs)
 '
 'This is the part in question
 AddHandler f.DataGridView1_CellClick, FillForm1(rs, (index of the row clicked))
```

And...

```
Private Function FillForm1(rs As ADODB.RecordSet, i As Integer)
    'fill textboxes with record i values of the recordset
End Function
```

In form 2

Comment: Is the intention that "ChildForm" can stay open while the user interacts with "form 1" or should "ChildForm" be closed when the user clicks a cell in the DGV?

Comment: Yes, it should stay open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to raise an event with custom data is to declare and raise a custom event. This new event can be triggered within the *_CellClick* event handler of your `DataGridView`. Decoupling from the DataGridView in this manner will help to isolate and insulate any future changes.

**SelectedValueEventArgs class**
Create this class to hold the event information that  you want to pass to the Parent form, in your case, *Form1*

```
Public Class SelectedValueEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs
    Public Sub New(rs As ADODB.RecordSet, i As Integer)
        RecordSet = rs
        Index = i
    End Sub

    Public Property RecordSet As ADODB.RecordSet
    Public Property Index As Integer
End Class
```

**Declare the SelectedValueChanged event**

Declare the event you want to raise, with an appropriate name. I went for SelectedValueChanged. This event should be declared in your *Form2* class

```
Public Event SelectedValueChanged As EventHandler(Of SelectedValueEventArgs)
```

**Raise the event**

Within the _CellClick event handler of the DataGridView, set up the Event Args and raise the new event

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    Dim rs As ADODB.RecordSet = ' Set your ADOBB.RecordSet here
    Dim i As Integer = e.RowIndex
    Dim eventArgs As New SelectedValueEventArgs(rs, i)
    OnSelectedValueChanged(eventArgs)
End Sub

' This function will do the hard work of raising the event to parent forms
Protected Overridable Sub OnSelectedValueChanged(e As SelectedValueEventArgs)
    RaiseEvent SelectedValueChanged(Me, e)
End Sub
```

**Handle the event in your Parent Form**

Finally, in your Parent Form *(Form1)*, when you show *Form2* add a handler for the newly created/published event and then carry out the required action in the event handler (*form2_SelectedValueChanged*)

```
Private Sub btnButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Dim f As New Form2
    AddHandler f.SelectedValueChanged, AddressOf form2_SelectedValueChanged
    f.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub form2_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectedValueEventArgs)
    Debug.Print(e.Index)
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I didn't do it exactly like that, but I stored the information in a global variable whenever the event was called.